# Why does @Value as parameter of constructor fill the property correctly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My question is: Why does this piece of code correctly set the constructor parameter property `port`:

```
private final RedisServer redisServer;

public RedisTestConfiguration(@Value("${cache.port}") final int port) {
   this.redisServer = new RedisServer(port);
}
```

As of my understanding, `@Value("${cache.port}")` is resolved by a BeanPostProcessor called AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. Spring bean lifecycle works in a way that the constructor method is called before any BeanPostProcess, see picture below. Note The constructor is called before BeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization().

[image: Spring Bean life cycle]

How come this is still working?

Regards,

Bart

Comment: That's not the _only_ place that supplies autowired values. You might search in your IDE for places where the `@Autowired` class is used inside the Spring Context dependency.

Comment: Because these classes, assuming using component scanning, are detected early. Bean definitions are created, post processed and just after that the beans get contructed not earlier. It is actually resolved when the configuration metadata is being processed by either the configuration class processing or component-scanning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is supported by PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer

PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is a BeanFactoryPostProcessor. It collects @Value fields and updates bean definition in spring container. PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer should be created in the container before any bean is initialized.

Bean metadata is described here in the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-metadata

So, the flow is the following:
 1. Bean definition readers collect beans declarations in xml files or from java classes. Example, XmlBeanDefinitionReader.

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanDefinitionReader.html

2. Bean Factory Post Processors update bean definitions. Example, PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.
3. Spring container looks at the bean definition and creates beans(calls constructor) according to bean definition values.
   Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-class

So, the problem is that 
`As of my understanding, @Value("${cache.port}") is resolved by a BeanPostProcessor` is not correct. @Value is managed by BeanFactoryPostProcessor, not BeanPostProcessor

Actually, documentation states:

`A default lenient embedded value resolver is provided by Spring. It will try to resolve the property value and if it cannot be resolved, the property name (for example ${catalog.name}) will be injected as the value. If you want to maintain strict control over nonexistent values, you should declare a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean, as the following example shows:...`

Spring has some kind of default property resolver, that is another BeanFactoryPostProcessor. But it is possible to override it with PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer